# Linux programs don't start after Oracle Java SDK installaltion

Tags: java, android, linux, java-8

I installed a new Sabayon Linux 64bit on my disc. Furtheron I installed Android Studio and replaced OpenJDK(icedtea) with Oracle Java SE SDK. It is installed and working so far:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

As far as I can see everything works fine, except for two programs: *android-studio* and *freecol*.

Here I have the console output for android-studio:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0

(java:7545): Gtk-WARNING **: Im Modulpfad »adwaita« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden,

(java:7545): Gtk-WARNING **: Im Modulpfad »adwaita« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden,
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@1ed6993a for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/opt/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/mrt/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna8216112928634011661.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/mrt/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna8216112928634011661.tmp
[    209]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.initIDs(Ljava/lang/Class;)V 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.initIDs(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.initIDs(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.<clinit>(FreetypeFontScaler.java:50)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at sun.font.FontScaler.<clinit>(FontScaler.java:98)
    at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.getScaler(TrueTypeFont.java:1298)
```

Any hints on that?

Comment: Looks like it's a current bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229727&q=java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError%3A%20sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.initIDs&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: FYI: In my case, it was working with icedtea.